# What was done to calculate the Ramsey numbers using a quantum computer?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, ramsey-theory

I recently came across [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1842v1) titled

> Experimental determination of Ramsey numbers with quantum annealing

I was wondering what exactly the gist of the paper, as I read it, it seems rather trivial that could be achieved by a normal computer.

Comment: What seems trivial? Calculating small Ramsey numbers or implementing quantum annealing? I think the point of the paper is the latter.

Comment: The importance is that they actually computed it with hardware.  See [this article](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/426586/worlds-largest-quantum-computation-uses-84-qubits/).

Comment: What doesn't seem to be discussed is whether this approach would be effective for determining $R(5,5)$, $R(6,6)$, etc. in a reasonable amount of time.